# Angular: Form control usage for nested controls

Tags: angular, accessibility

I have e.g. an Angular Material Tab-Group and use reactive forms. Since I want to avoid to generate long HTML files I encapsulate some parts as own components. e.g.

```
<form fromGroup="form">
  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Details"><app-details-component></app-details-component></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Notes"><app-notes-component></app-notes-component></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Logging"><app-logging-component></app-logging-component></mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</form>
```

Now I can use on each of the `app-...-components` either `form`, e.g.

```
// app-details-component
<form form="form">
   <input matInput ...>
   ...
```

or can implement my own `ControlValueAccessor` for each of the component. With `ControlValueAccessor`  I can avoid the usage of `form`.

So, I'm not clear if this kind of design-pattern is correct overall.

Background: Since we try to make the application accessible as much as possible I'm highly suspicious about the nested usage of `form`. But I didn't find any source if there is a problem with multiple nested `form`s. Do multiple nested `form` elements effect a screenreader (for accibility)? (also further resources are highly appreciated)

Comment: Nested `<form>` elements are not allowed. It's not valid HTML.

Comment: You have any hint where this is mentioned? Just for the sake of completeness...

Comment: Check W3C Validator and add some HTML (there’s no option to share a custom version of it with my HTML)

Comment: The HTML spec mentions it (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element)  Look at the "content model" section.  It says *"Flow content, **but with no form element descendants**."*